# How to generate the valadoc for a C library (or any library whose bindings ships with vala)?

Tags: documentation, vala, gobject-introspection

I want to re-generate the [`valadoc`](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Valadoc) for the gnome `gio-2.0` library (that is part of `glib`).

I'm aware that the complete documentation is [available online](http://valadoc.org/#!wiki=gio-2.0/index).

I want to be able **to generate it locally** (ideally without having to rebuild the library myself).

Valadoc is able to generate the documentation from the gobject-introspection file (the gir file) that is created during the library compilation.
This file contains all the definitions and comments.

Hopefully for me, [a central repository](https://github.com/nemequ/vala-girs) is maintained by the vala team and the [Gio-2.0.gir](https://github.com/nemequ/vala-girs/blob/master/gir-1.0/Gio-2.0.gir) is available.

Now that I downloaded the file, I'm having issues invoking valadoc with the proper parameters.

The following commands:

```
valadoc --girdir=. --importdir=. --import=Gio-2.0 --pkg=gio-2.0 --force -o ./dist
```

or

```
valadoc --pkg=gio-2.0 --force -o ./dist
```

Returns

```
Succeeded - 0 warning(s)
```

And create an html with only the package names but no classes/methods/etc.

**Could you help me to invoke valadoc properly?**

> **note :** for anyone curious about how the complete [valadoc.org](http://valadoc.org/) gets generated, the scripts and apps [are available](https://gitorious.org/valadoc-org/valadoc-org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already done, you can specify the needed packages via `--pkg gtk+-3.0` for example. In order to make the docs generated for those, you also have to specify `--deps` (without any extra arguments).

EDIT: probably of interest as well: to actually have doc strings included, you need to set the `--importdir` parameter to your gir directory (most of the time that's `/usr/share/gir-1.0`) and add e.g. `--import=Gio-2.0` for each package from which you want doc strings. If you have vapis that have been generated with comments kept, you probably won't need this extra step.